# Is there a way to delay irssi's channel re-join during reconnect until after auth has occurred?

Tags: irssi

When I am connected to an invite-only channel and I experience a network outage, there's a race condition between automatic auth'ing and rejoining channels. (ETA: If it matters, I'm using CertFP (client SSL cert) to auth.) If auth is too slow, irssi removes the windows for invite-only channels.

Is there a way to delay channel reconnect, or in some other way solve this race condition?

(If I can't, as an alternative I would at least like to keep irssi from closing the windows!)

Comment: Many (most?) IRC daemons support receiving NickServ passwords as server passwords. I'd recommend checking to see if your IRC network supports it as it would be a much better solution to your ultimate goal.

Comment: I'm actually using SSL cert authentication, but there's still a race somehow. :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://irssi.org/documentation/startup/ in particular (OFTC network, identify with `nickserv` and wait for 2 seconds before joining channels)

```
/NETWORK ADD -autosendcmd "/^msg nickserv ident pass;wait 2000" OFTC
```

Likely, in your case you will simply add `;wait 2000` to your `auth` command. Note, it belongs inside the double-quotation marks.

Comment: Oooh, interesting! I have a wait *before* identifying, makes sense that I might want a wait after as well! I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Hmm. I should temper that with two observations: 1) On this network I'm auth'ing with CertFP (SSL client cert), which might change timing, and 2) my question is specifically about reconnects, and I'm not sure how this interacts with that. Still, adding autosendcmd = "wait 1000"; to my chatnet config and we'll see.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be working well! Thanks!

Comment: Also, as explained in [OFTC documentation](https://oftc.net/NickServ/CertFP/#irssi-does-not-join-some-channels-on-connect), just `/network add -autosendcmd "wait -oftc 2000" OFTC` should be enough if you already have automatic identification set up.